# Format GridView column 2 SQL column values to be separated by a symbol

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, eval, templatefield

I have a GridView with one column which contains 2 values from SQL, from columns Author and Author2. 
In my table there is only one row which has values in both columns, others have only one Author and a NULL. I want to separate only those with both authors with a symbol "&".

I have tried doing this several ways, the first one is with CSS:

```
<head>
<style> 
.label2css:before {
content: "& ";
}
</style>  
</head>
```

...

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Author") %>'></asp:Label> 
<asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="label2css" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author2") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and the other one:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Author") %>'></asp:Label> 
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# "&" + Eval("Author2") %>'>   </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

But both resulted in this:
Author & 
Author & Author2
Author &

But I want to be able to do this:
Author
Author & Author2
Author

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If I remember correctly there should be a way to use the databind event to manipulate the output. This way you can check for null in the code behind and set the value of author2 as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Author") %>'></asp:Label> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#  String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Author2") as string) ? "" : Eval("Author2", "& {0}") %>'>   </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Here's my test code.**

The markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Author") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Author2") as string) ? "" : Eval("Author2", "& {0}") %>'>   </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code:

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.DataSource = new List<MyClass>(){
            new MyClass { Author="Author"},
            new MyClass { Author="Author", Author2="Author2"},
            new MyClass { Author="Author"}

        };

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Author2 { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you, @afzalulh! I was able to do it based on your code like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```